# What is the opencv equivalent to matlab's fliplr()?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

My solution is:

```
cv::Mat FlipLR(const cv::Mat& inImg)
{
    //create flipped image from Left to right
    cv::Mat outImg(inImg.size(), inImg.type());
    cv::Mat_<double> FlipMatrix(2, 3);
    FlipMatrix << -1, 0, inImg.cols - 1, 
        0, 1, 0; 

    cv::warpAffine( inImg, outImg, FlipMatrix, outImg.size(), cv::INTER_NEAREST );

    return outImg;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [cv::flip()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#flip).

Although a simple search through the docs would've given you this.

Answer (score 2):

**fliplr :**

```
cv::flip(imImg, outImg, 1);
```

---

**flipud :**

```
cv::flip(imImg, outImg, 0);
```